# os-commerce how to add a transaction/handling fee?

Tags: e-commerce, oscommerce

I have a client that has an active oscommerce site. They've requested that we add a $2.00 transaction or handling fee to every order, no restrictions. I have never used oscommerce before, only Magento.

How can I accomplish this using a plugin or hand-coding? The client uses Paypal Website Payments Standard.

Comment: why dont you make a `tax class` and add the `description` as `handling fee`..

Comment: I'll give that a go here shortly. Thanks

Comment: you come online on http://forums.oscommerce.com/chat/ for online help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to get this working simply by tweaking [this module](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/7003). Then did a simply overwrite of the `includes/modules/order_total/ot_handling.php` file to always have a $2.00 fee.